# How to get a formula to extend to new cells depending on pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a pivot table with some formulas using the data from the pivot table to the side of it. My problem is that if I add a filter, say city, so that the pivot table extends down, the formulas to the side don't extend down as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a calculated field in the Pivot Table itself. You can then add this to the values section.

To create one, look in the ANALYZE tab for "Fields, Items & Sets".

UPDATE: If your formulae are too complex, you could try using the Microsoft PowerQuery addin to see if you can calculate things a different way.

The only other alternative I can think of is to write some VBA to insert/remove cells with the formula whenever the pivot table updates. But that is not a nice way to go.

Comment: I can't work with calculated fields because the formulas are too complex

Comment: Please see my update. Also you should share the formula if you can and some example data to give people a chance to come up with an alternative approach.